# ngx-bootstrap AlertModule Issue

Tags: angular5, ngx-bootstrap

It was working nicely when i used "angular4" and "ngx-bootstrap 1.9.3". i have updated project to angular 5.. Seems only Alert is not working. 
If i remove **alert**  element from html template it will be fine.

Alert module is imported in shared.module.ts

`import { AlertModule } from "ngx-bootstrap/alert";`

```
@NgModule({
imports: [AlertModule.forRoot()]})
```

.html

```
<alert type="{{alertType}}" dismissible="true">{{alertMessage}}</alert>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngx-bootstrap 1.9.3 only supports angular 2 and 4. Please update to the latest version (2.0.2) and it will work fine with angular 5